# Issue with Microsoft Sign in Code converted to VB.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure-active-directory, owin

I'm converting my asp.net mvc web app to use MS single sign on and i'm following the guide located here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp

My app is in vb.net so i've had to convert the code - i'm running into one error after the conversion which has me stumped. Here are the 2 functions that i've converted and placed in the Startup.vb class in my project:

```
    'Configure OWIN to use OpenIdConnect
    Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)
    
        ' app.SanitizeThreadCulture()
        app.MapSignalR()
    
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions With {
            .ClientId = clientId,
            .Authority = authority,
            .RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            .PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            .Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            .ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
            .TokenValidationParameters = New TokenValidationParameters() With {
                .ValidateIssuer = False
            },
            .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications With {
                .AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed()
        }
        })
    
    End Sub
    
'Handle failed authentication requests by redirecting the user to the home page with an error in the query string
    Private Function OnAuthenticationFailed(ByVal context As AuthenticationFailedNotification(Of OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions)) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Integer)
        context.HandleResponse()
        context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" & context.Exception.Message)
        Return Task.FromResult(0)
    End Function
```

The error is on the line: .AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed() saying argument not supplier for parameter "context" of OnAuthenticationFailed ...  The C# version of the code in the documentation (link above) does not pass any parameters and I can't seem to find any examples online of other people having issues with this line of code.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by using a lamda expression to call the AuthenticationFailed method inline.  At that point it allowed me to pass the context.

```
 Public Sub Configuration(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)

        app.MapSignalR()

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions With {
            .ClientId = clientId,
            .Authority = authority,
            .PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            .RedirectUri = redirectUri,
             .Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            .ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
            .TokenValidationParameters = New TokenValidationParameters() With {
                .ValidateIssuer = False
            },
            .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications With {
                .AuthenticationFailed = Function(context)
                                            context.HandleResponse()
                                            context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index")
                                            Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                        End Function
            }
        })
    End Sub
```